# Kinesis Lambda Consumer Minimum Batch Size

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, batch-processing, amazon-kinesis

I'm using AWS Lambda (node.js) as a AWS Kinesis Consumer. I can see that you can set a maximum batch size, but I'm wondering if I can set a minimum batch size. So that I can insure that each lambda will handle at least 50 (or any number) records.

I'd like to have a minimum batch size because the lambda consumer will be establishing a connection to a RDS MySQL instance and I'm trying to keep the number of concurrent connections low.

If there isn't a config capability that would set a minimum, any workaround ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One way could be to use Kinesis Firehose, which concatenates multiple incoming records based on buffering configuration of your delivery stream.

1. [Send data to Firehose](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/basic-write.html) - Either directly put records to Firehose Stream using their API, or attach the Firehose to your existing kinesis stream.
2. [Set S3 as your Firehose's destination](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/create-destination.html) - This will essentially aggregate your individual records, and put them in S3 as a single object. You can specify your delimiters, and even transformation lambda functions on single records.
3. [Listen for S3:PutObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html) - Attach your lambda to listen to the S3 bucket which receives these aggregated records from the Firehose stream.

Comment: this would perform very poorly on a high throughput system as it would generate a large amount of small files and a lot of s3 triggers, which are hard to monitor and have very loose SLA

Answer (score 0):

First question I have is how many shards do you have open in the stream? You only get 1 instance of the lambda per shard concurrently executing. So if you only have 1 shard then you'll only have 1 lambda at a time hitting your RDS instance anyway.

> Do you have data that indicates it's a problem?

What follows is a ***hack*** which may or may not work reliably. And should probably not be used in a prod environment.

For a minimum batch size, you could return an `error` from your node.js lambda function if the batch size is less then your desired number of records.

E.g.

```
handler(event, context, callback) {
  const records = event.Records;
  if (records.length() < minBatchSize) {
    callback('insufficient batch size');
  } else {
    processRecords(records, callback);
  }
}
```

***BUT*** two problems come to mind:

1) You can't do this indefinitely without running the risk of losing data as there is a maximum event time limit that is configured on your stream. After this time the records disappear from the stream. Note that you pay extra for this feature (see [extended data retention](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/streams/pricing/)).

You may be able to infer batch age from the lambda / kinesis shard iterator age metrics see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/monitoring-with-cloudwatch.html.

I'm not sure how reliable this is, especially if you have more than 1 shard, but e.g.

```
handler(event, context, callback) {
  const records = event.Records;
  if (records.length() < minBatchSize) {
    if (calculateLambdaAge() > tooLongDelayThreshold) {
      processRecords(records, callback);
    } else {
      callback(new Error('insufficient batch size'));
    }
  } else {
    processRecords(records, callback);
  }
}

calculateLambdaAge() {
  // interrogate cloudwatch
}
```

If cloudwatch won't tell you, you may need to keep track of it yourself somewhere that's at least as scalable as your RDS (redis / dynamo).

2) Instead of putting the effort into making #1 reliable, could that extra effort just go into scaling up your RDS instance making your current usage more efficient?

---

I've referred to [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html) and [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/eventsources.html#eventsources-kinesis-streams) when putting together the code samples.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis.html), returning an error makes the lambda reprocess the same batch...